# Collapse button on right side of navbar shows links on left side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

first post on SO so sorry if my format is horrible. Just a quick question about a custom fixed-top navbar I'm working on (and I'm very new to Bootstrap and CSS in general). It has a logo as the brand, and three links on the right, one of which is a dropdown, there's also a media query for the the links to collapse sooner (which I found here on SO!). However, when the window is re-sized, and the collapse button is clicked all of the links drop down on the complete left side like it's coming from under the brand. I just want a simple accordion style dropdown for the collapse and for the actual dropdown. Any input is very much appreciated!
Here is the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#topFixedNavbar1"  aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Top Tier Math"></a></div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">



    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right links">
      <li><a href="#">How We Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Abous Us</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I also added some css to change the height of the navbar for the logo but I doubt this is the cause. Here it is though.

```
.navbar-default{
height:120px;
}
.navbar-header, .navbar-brand{
height:120px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;   
}

#topFixedNavbar1{
height:120px;
}

.links{
height:120px;

}

.navbar-nav li a{
line-height:90px;


}

.dropdown li a{
line-height:30px;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
/* since 3.1.0 */
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
    display: block!important;
}
.collapsing {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide us the full CSS file ?

Comment: This is all the css i've used for the page. I'm working with this on a test page exclusively for the menu. In addition to the 4000+ lines of bootstrap code. I left out some of the html for the collapse code. I'll edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want them to display but just use CSS to control the position of the dropdown.

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
  width:
  margin:
}
```

You should be able to add styles to this and it will move and change the dropdown.

Comment: I added that it definitely changed the width and margin of the links in the collapse area however they're still completely on the left side, and I want them just to pop down underneath the collapse button on the right side (like you would think it would do automatically) I don't think I can post an image but I have a snippet of what it looks like EDIT: added a snippet here: http://imgur.com/0FYrhxz

Comment: Wow, don't know why I didn't just set width to 100% to start and change coloring and what not. Awesome, thanks a lot!